# Quote only the required columns using pandas to_csv

Tags: python, pandas, csv, export-to-csv, quoting

I need to generate a csv using pandas to_csv function. I tried quote=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC. But for one of the date time column I dont need double quotes.

Is there a way to select the columns for which we want double quotes?

Comment: You might want to tag this as python, too.

Comment: @Sowmika Please share the dataframe sample(2-3) rows or df.dtypes

Answer (score 8):

Thanks people. I got the answer so just thought to share.

First I got the list of headers to be quoted and looped them something like below:

```
for col in quoteColumnsList:
    df[col] = '"' + df[col] + '"'
```

Here my quotechar is '"'. Now I used to_csv with quote parameter as csv.QUOTE_NONE. This way we get the double quotes only to the required columns.

Answer (score 0):

This worked better for me:

```
columnsList = data.columns #(or specific columns that you need)
for col in columnsList:
   data[col] =  data[col].apply(lambda x: "" + str(x) + "")
```

Example: For my project, I had to add quotes and convert them to list.

```
def convert_list(data):
    columnsList = data.columns
    for col in columnsList :
        data[col] =  data[col].apply(lambda x: "" + str(x) + "") #this adds single quotes without specifying it as "'")
    df = data.values.tolist()
    return df
```