# Pandas exporting to_csv() with quotation marks around column names

Tags: pandas, csv, escaping, export-to-csv, quoting

For some reason I need to output to a csv in this format with quotations around each columns names, my desired output looks like:

```
"date" "ret"
2018-09-24 0.00013123989025119056
```

I am trying with

```
import csv
import pandas as pd

Y_pred.index.name = "\"date\""
Y_pred.name = "\'ret\'"
Y_pred = Y_pred.to_frame()
path = "prediction/Q1/"
try:
    os.makedirs(path)
except:
    pass

Y_pred.to_csv(path+instrument_tmp+"_ret.txt",sep=' ')
```

and got outputs like:

```
"""date""" 'ret'
2018-09-24 0.00013123989025119056
```

I can't seem to find a way to use quotation to wrap at the columns. Does anyone know how to? Thanks.

**My solution:**
using quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE together with Y_pred.index.name = "\"date\"", Y_pred.name = "\"ret\""

```
Y_pred.index.name = "\"date\""
Y_pred.name = "\"ret\""
Y_pred = Y_pred.to_frame()
path = "prediction/Q1/"
try:
    os.makedirs(path)
except:
    pass

Y_pred.to_csv(path+instrument_tmp+"_ret.txt",sep=' ',quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
```

and then I get

```
"date" "ret"
2018-09-24 0.00013123989025119056
```

Comment: This is called ***quoted output***. In general there is no need to manually hack quotes into the column names. Use one of the `quoting=csv.QUOTE_...` options

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Quote only the required columns using pandas to\_csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47647319/quote-only-the-required-columns-using-pandas-to-csv)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IIUC, you can use the `quoting` argument with [`csv.QUOTE_NONE`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html)

```
import csv
df.to_csv('test.csv',sep=' ',quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
```

And your resulting csv will look like:

```
 "date" "ret"
0 2018-09-24 0.00013123989025119056
```

**Side Note**: To facilitate the adding of quotations to your columns, you can use `add_prefix` and `add_suffix`. If your starting dataframe looks like:

```
>>> df
         date       ret
0  2018-09-24  0.000131
```

Then do:

```
df = df.add_suffix('"').add_prefix('"')
df.to_csv('test.csv',sep=' ',quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
```

Comment: is this version dependent? I didn't get the desired output when quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE

Comment: I wouldn't think so, but just for reference I'm using '0.21.1'

Answer (score 6):

This is called ***quoted output***.
Instead of manually hacking in quotes into your column names (which will mess with other dataframe functionality), use the `quoting` option:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"date": ["2018-09-24"], "ret": [0.00013123989025119056]})

df.to_csv("out_q_esc.txt", sep=' ', escapechar='\\', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL, index=None)
"date" "ret"
"2018-09-24" "0.00013123989025119056"
```

The 'correct' way is to use `quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL` (and optionally `escapechar='\\'`), but note however that `QUOTE_ALL` will force **all** columns to be quoted, even obviously numeric ones like the index; if we hadn't specified `index=None`, we would get:

```
"" "date" "ret"
"0" "2018-09-24" "0.00013123989025119056"
```

- `csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL` refuses to quote these fields because they don't strictly need quotes (they're neither multiline nor do they contain internal quote or separator chars)