# Individually define columns to be quoted when writing to CSV using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, export-to-csv

I want to convert my pandas dataframe to a csv file. My dataframe has more than 100 columns of different data types and different (date- and number-) formats. That makes it difficult to create a csv file that fulfills the requirements: Strings in Quotes, Numbers and Dates not in Quotes. For example I have date values like this: `24.07.2019 08:31:28.764000000` that should NOT be quoted, but Strings have to be quoted.

I've tried all different combination of pandas' `to_csv()`:

- `quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC`
- `quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL`
- `quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL`
- `quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE`

Most suitable is `QUOTE_NONNUMERIC` but dates as mentioned above are quoted anyway.

Is there any way to individually define which columns should be quoted and which columns shouldn't without looping over all values?

Comment: You're not going to be able to achieve that sort of quoting with `to_csv()`. Use `csv.QUOTE_NONE`, iterate over each dataframe row and write to a csv file. [Look here for further info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19315366/csv-writer-in-python-with-custom-quoting). Slow but it works.

Comment: This seems like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47647319/quote-only-the-required-columns-using-pandas-to-csv. The best answer there should provide a solution.

Answer (score 0):

The second answer in this link worked for me.
[Quote only the required columns using pandas to_csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47647319/quote-only-the-required-columns-using-pandas-to-csv)

```py
columnsList = data.columns #(or specific columns that you need)
for col in columnsList:
   data[col] =  data[col].apply(lambda x: "" + str(x) + "")
```